# Connecting to AWS RDS database using beanstalk and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In PHP 7, As I try to connect to the Beanstalk I have set up, I receive the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysql' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\php_file.php, Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\php_file.php on line 41.

This server uses AWS RDS running MYSQL, and I am using apache 2.4 to localhost (for testing).

The code I'm using is:

```
$servername = "MY BEANSTALK CONNECTION";
$username = "Username";
$password = "PSSWD";
$dbname = "DBNAME";

$conn = new mysql($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM column";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$conn->close();
```

My updated code uses mysqli, but is still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHP documentation `mysql` class is deprecated since version 5.5 and removed in version 7. that's why you're receiving the class not found error.

Try using `mysqli`. The PHP documentation has good examples on this. Look at example 2. I've pasted part of the example in this post for you.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'choices to please everybody.' AS _msg FROM DUAL");
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['_msg'];
?>
```

Comment: Is the problem you're having with the RDS instance or your local instance?

Answer (score -1):

Use mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) instead.

Comment: `mysql_connect` was deprecated in 5.5 and removed in PHP 7.0 in favor of using `mysqli_connect`. In this particular case Luke was asking about PHP 7.